# What is the correct way to share R data on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

I see a lot of [R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) questions where the OP refers to a specific `data.frame` or other data structure. Often, they include an image of the `data.frame`. This has several drawbacks, including not being able to easily pull the data into `R` for testing possible solutions.

Is there a preferred, or more useful, way to include a `data.frame` so it's easier  to use the data in `R`, and reach a solution?

Comment: Exactly, it would be good to have a recommendation on how to export data from `R` into SO to make it easy to use in a solution, or pull back into `R`. For example, using `head(df)` you can output a sample of data, copy and paste it into SO, and format it as code. That works fairly well for giving users an idea of the `data.frame`. Is there a good method for copying this and getting it back into `R` using something like `read.delim()`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a question on StackOverflow on [how to make a good reproducible example for R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4303162). The answers contain many good suggestions, how data could be shared (`dput()`, using one of the standard R data sets instead of real data, ...).

If data is printed with `dput()`, it can be stored in a variable by a simple 
assignment:

```r
x <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 5:7)
dput(x)
## structure(list(a = 1:3, b = 5:7), .Names = c("a", "b"), row.names = c(NA, 
## -3L), class = "data.frame")

y <- structure(list(a = 1:3, b = 5:7), .Names = c("a", "b"),
           row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
y
##   a b
## 1 1 5
## 2 2 6
## 3 3 7
```

If someone asks a question and posts his data as a picture or in another inconvenient way, you could make a comment and direct him to the post that I linked above.

The question is also listed in the [r-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-faq) and in the [R tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) (thanks to [rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene) for the hint).

Comment: I hadn't come across this somehow.

Comment: I was going to say that the content of that question should maybe be in the tag-wiki but I see that question is part of the [tag:r-faq] which might be worth mentioning as well.